# Wrong number of args passed to: repl$repl

Tags: clojure, compojure, leiningen

I have a trouble with a compojure "Getting started" example that I do notunderstand. When I run the example from http://weavejester.github.com/compojure/docs/getting-started.html

...I get the following error at the lein repl step:

```
~/hello-www> lein repl src/hello_www/core.clj
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args passed to: repl$repl (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5359)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5311)
    at clojure.core$eval__4350.invoke(core.clj:2364)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt__6502.invoke(main.clj:228)
    at clojure.main$initialize__6506.invoke(main.clj:247)
    at clojure.main$script_opt__6526.invoke(main.clj:263)
    at clojure.main$main__6544.doInvoke(main.clj:347)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:483)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:180)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args passed to: repl$repl
    at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:439)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:43)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:369)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
    at clojure.core$apply__3776.invoke(core.clj:535)
    at leiningen.core$_main__59$fn__61.invoke(core.clj:94)
    at leiningen.core$_main__59.doInvoke(core.clj:91)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:138)
    at clojure.core$apply__3776.invoke(core.clj:535)
    at leiningen.core$_main__59.invoke(core.clj:97)
    at user$eval__67.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5343)
    ... 11 more
```

I have tried both the stable and the developer version of lein without any success. Any ideas on what I could look for next? I get the same result both on linux and cygwin.

When I run it manually, it seems to work fine on linux:

```
java -cp "lib/*" clojure.main  src/hello_www/core.clj
2010-05-17 19:34:17.280::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2010-05-17 19:34:17.281::INFO:  jetty-6.1.14
2010-05-17 19:34:17.382::INFO:  Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: I checked that with Leiningen 1.1 the tutorial you linked to works fine for me. Do you have `lein-stable` set up properly? (One way to check would be to remove the `lib/` directory in your checkout of lein's HEAD and see if you can then do `lein-stable deps`.)

Comment: I used the latest leiningen from git. 1.2. With lein-stable it works, but not with master from git. Note that I followed the guide from "Hacking", first bootstrapping with stable before linking the git master version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account your comment on the question -- the relevant part is "With lein-stable it works, but not with master from git." -- I'd say that you're being hit by Leiningen's new handling of the `repl` task introduced in commit `44b6369aec1e23bcda1db1b6570a03ca524464e5` from 16th April 2010.

Leiningen 1.1 was released on 16th February and does things the old way, which means the `repl` task is handled specially by the `lein` script; post-`44b6369aec` Leiningen handles the `repl` task the same way as all the others, i.e. through the `leiningen.repl/repl` function. The latter simply doesn't accept additional arguments, hence the arity-related `IllegalArgumentException` that you're seeing. Before you ask, I'm not sure if that is likely to change in the future.

What should work is `lein repl` followed by `(require 'hello-www.core)`; regrettably, however, there seems to be an issue with Leiningen's HEAD which prevents that from working (at least on my box). It's a safe bet to expect that it's going to get fixed eventually, but for the time being, just use `lein-stable`. That Compojure tutorial uses Clojure 1.1 and not the bleeding edge... It might save you some time to treat Leiningen the same way.

Comment: Thanks Michal. I will follow your advice.